# MYSQL one to many relationship query returning a single row from 'many' table

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, limit

I have 2 mysql tables namely 'properties' and 'images'.

```
          Properties
  +------------+---------------+
  | propertyId | propertyTitle |  
  +------------+---------------+
  |          1 | 1 acre land   |  
  |          2 | 2 acre land   |  
  |          3 | 3 acre land   |  
  +------------+---------------+

                Images
  +---------+---------------+---------------+
  | imageId |     image     |  propertyId   |  
  +---------+---------------+---------------+
  |       1 | land.jpeg     |        1      |
  |       2 | landview.jpg  |        1      |
  |       3 | viewland.jpeg |        2      |
  +---------+---------------+---------------+
```

They have a one-many relationship and the images table has a foreign key of the properties table. I would like to perform a query that selects a property and then selects a single image of the property. 
The query i'm trying to work with is

```
   SELECT * FROM properties p
    JOIN (SELECT * FROM images im LIMIT 1)
    ON im.propertyId = p.propertyId;
```

Its not working though. Neither does it return an error.

Comment: Which image do you want to select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can handle this problem using two joins.  First, join the properties table to the images table as you suspected in your question.  Then, do an additional to join to a subquery which finds the first image for each property.

```
SELECT
    p.propertyId,
    p.propertyTitle,
    i1.image
FROM properties p
INNER JOIN images i1
    ON p.propertyId = i1.propertyId
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT propertyId, MIN(imageId) AS min_imageId
    FROM images
    GROUP BY propertyId
) i2
    ON i1.propertyId = i2.propertyId AND
       i1.imageId = t2.min_imageId;
```

Comment: What is t1 aliasing?

Comment: @VictorNgure Sorry, that was a typo.  It should have been `i1.imageId`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want returns all rows, your query will become:

```
SELECT * FROM properties p
JOIN images im
ON im.propertyId = p.propertyId;
```

Using `LIMIT 1` you return only one row from your images table so you have a limitation about your rows

**EDIT**

After comments:

In this way you'll get the first image linked to your property.

```
SELECT p.*,
    (SELECT im.mage
    FROM images im
    WHERE im.propertyId = p.propertyId
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 'NEXT'
        FROM images im2
        WHERE im.propertyId = im2.propertyId
        AND im2.imageId > im.imageId)
    )
FROM properties p;
```

Comment: I would like to return only a single row from the images table.

Comment: @VictorNgure: In your case between image linked to propertyId 1 which you want to return?

Comment: Any of the images linked to property 1

Comment: @VictorNgure This makes no sense.  You need to give us logic for which image to select for a given a property from among the possible images.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The logic is when a user submits a property, the first image they upload will be used as the cover of the property. The rest of  the images willbe accessible when the user clicks on a specific property.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query,

```
SELECT * FROM properties p
JOIN images im
ON im.propertyId = p.propertyId
where p.propertyTitle = '1 acre land'
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: In this way you'll get only one row of join. Our OP wants one row for property

Comment: Won't this return both images?

Comment: @VictorNgure you need to remove `LIMIT 1`